# Unable to increase worker memory above 2GB in sparkling water shell

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

When running the `sparkling-shell` :

```
bin/sparkling-shell
```

The following error occurs:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Asked to launch cluster with 2048 MB RAM / worker but requested 20480 MB/worker
```

We have set following in `spark-env.sh` :

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=108GB
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4
```

And the following in `spark-defaults.conf` :

```
spark.executor.memory   20g
spark.driver.memory     8g
```

The only way we can get the shell to launch is to reset to 2GB the worker memory:

```
spark.executor.memory   2g
```

But that is simply way insufficient for running our jobs.   Anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: RE: Vote to close .  You probably do not realize that sparkling-water shell were a *programming* artifact related to Spark.  This question does not belong - say - in `superuser`.  Note that all apache-spark related questions have been *explicitly* mentioned as supposed to be *here* - according to the spark mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Can I please ask to what is content of your `MASTER` environment variable ?

This can occur if you have set `MASTER` to `"local-cluster[numOfExecutors,numOfExecutorCores,numOfExecMemory]"` where `numOfExecMemory` is lower then your request for memory in spark-defaults file.

Comment: MASTER is just set to `spark://myhost:7077` - standard fare.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your spark-defaults.conf file :

```
spark.executor.memory   20g
spark.driver.memory     8g
```

Here spark.executor.memory is set to 20g (20 gigabytes = 20480 mb) which translates to 20480 mb per worker node. Therefore the error -->

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Asked to launch cluster with 2048 MB RAM / worker but requested 20480 MB/worker
```

where it says you have asked to form cluster with 20480 mb per worker.

You should edit the `spark.executor.memory  20g` spark-defaults.conf file to `spark.executor.memory   2g`

If you want to increase the memory per worker just change 2g to the mount you want.

Also edit the spark-env.sh accordingly as this :

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=108GB
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4
```

will create 4 worker instances per node with 1 gb memory each.

So if you want for example 4gb each node then in spark-env.sh

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
```

and spark-defaults.conf as :

```
spark.executor.memory   4g
spark.driver.memory     8g
```

Comment: This is not a typo --  what is wrong with 20g per worker?  I had seen the problem *starting* at 2g .. but that is different from the amount of ram we actually need.

Comment: This is not an Sparkling Water issue, but matter of configuring your spark jobs with correct memory configuration.

You can set and override any spark configuration as part of `sparkling-shell` by passing it extra arguments you would normally pass to `spark-submit`